# Bifurcation Example Using Newton's Method

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods, dynamical-systems, newton-raphson

I am studying dynamical systems as part of a research project. 
I have been using Newton's Method and studying the dynamic properties.
Does anyone know where I could find a relatively simple example of bifurcation using Newton's Method?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an illustration of the comment that I made 5 hours ago.  The idea is to examine the dynamics of $f_c(x)=x^2+c$ for various choices of $c$. When $c<0$, there are two real roots. When $c>0$, there are no real roots. Thus, we expect a distinct change in behavior as $c$ passes through zero.

In the animation below, $f_c(x)=x^2+c$ is the light parabola and the corresponding Newton's method iteration function
$$n_c(x)=\frac{x^2-c}{2x}$$
is shown in blue.  The diagonal black line is the graph of $y=x$ and the intersection of this line with the graph of $n_c(x)$ are the fixed points of $n_c$.  The extreme bifurcation at zero happens because the fixed points of $n_c$ correspond to the roots of $f_c$, which disappear.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help that makes sense - any ideas how I would go about programming a similar animation into maple?

Comment: @Neil Nope - I'm a Mathematica guy. :)  You might also look at the family $f(z)=z^5-z-\lambda$, which has a nice sequence of period doubling bifurcations around $\lambda=1$.